# Existence of unitary operator that transforms phase gates

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-computer

Let me first introduce the entire problem:
Let $H$ be an Hermitian operator, $W$ be an Unitary operator and let $S$ be the standard phase gate: $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & i\end{pmatrix}$. These can all be represented by $2\times2$ matrices.
Define the following function:
$$
f_{ab}^{W}(H) = \phi_{ab}S_{b}^{\dagger}W^{\dagger}HWS_a 
$$
Where $\phi_{ab} = \frac{1}{2}i^{a-b}$. Also $a$ and $b$ can take on the values $0$ and $1$ and $S_0 = S$ while $S_1 = S^{\dagger}$. 
One can fairly easy show the following three properties of this function:
\begin{align}
f_{ab}^{W}(c_1A + c_2B) &= c_1f_{ab}^{W}(A) + c_2f_{ab}^W(B) \\
f_{ab}^{W}(H)^{\dagger} &= f_{ba}^W(H)\\
\sum_{a,b}f_{ab}^{W}(H) &= W^{\dagger}HW
\end{align}

After doing some numerical experiments with this function, I ended up conjecturing the following:
There exists a $W$ such that the following expression holds:
$$
f_{00}^W(H) + f_{11}^W(H) = f_{00}^U(H) + f_{01}^U(H) + f_{10}^U(H) + f_{11}^U(H) = U^{\dagger}HU
$$
Where $U$ is some unitary gate.
However I am unable to prove this.
Does somebody have suggestions on how to start this existence proof?

Comment: Why do you care about this? This looks completely contrived. Also, what is the "standard phase gate"? -- Note that the middle part of your expression (with 00, 01, 10, 11) looks like it can be factorized.

Comment: With standard phase gate I mean $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & i\end{pmatrix}$ (I will edit this in the post). I am interested in this because I am using this function for my research in Quantum Circuit Partitioning. Without going to much into depth, I am decomposing 2-qubit gates in weighted sums of 1-qubit gates. But the number of terms in the total sum grows exponentially, that is why I am looking for way to eliminate circuit evaluations by finding these identities.

Comment: I am a bit confused about your conjecture. Is it only that LHS=RHS, or what is the role of the expression in the middle?

Comment: The part in the middle is equal to $\sum_{a,b}f_{a,b}^{U}(H)$ which I wrote above. The conjecture is "Do there exist operators $W$ and $U$ such that we can transform only the $f_{00} + f_{11}$ to the entire sum."

Comment: Can you be more clear about the conjecture? Is it "There exists a W and a U, such that for every H? Or is it "For every H there exists W and U such that"? This is a huge difference.

Comment: Hm, I see (about the expression in the middle). Wouldn't the conjecture be more crisp without the part in the middle? (It would be the same conjecture.)

Comment: Part 2 and part 3 are equal, I calculated this. What the conjecture asks is "For every H does there exist a W and U such that the LHS and middle part are equal."

Comment: Can you please rewrite the question accordingly? (I also feel it would be much more concise without even defining $f$ -- just spelling everything out in terms of the definition of W, which you only use twice in the conjecture, in fact.)

Comment: Note that in that case, the conjecture is simply that the LHS and H have the same spectrum. This is indeed true if you choose W such that it diagonalized H.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $W$ which diagonalizes $H$. Then,
$W^\dagger H W=D$ is diagonal, and thus
$$
f_{aa}^W(H) = \tfrac12 S_a^\dagger D S_a = \tfrac12 D\ ,
$$
as $S_a$ is diagonal (and unitary).

Then, clearly
$$
f_{00}^W(H) + f_{11}^W(H) = D = W^\dagger H W\ ,
$$
which proves your conjecture with $U=W$.

Comment: Could there also be a $W$ such that $U\neq W$?